# Insert dash and capitalize first letter of arraylist

Tags: java, string, list

I've got `List` of `Strings`:

```
[a, b, b, c, c, c, d, d, d, d]
```

I need to insert dash and capitalize first letter like:

```
[A, -, B, b, -,  C, c, c, -, D, d, d, d]
```

I get letter which I need to move and set dash on it's place:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
         if (!list.get(i + 1).equals(list.get(i))) {
                System.out.println(list.get(i + 1));
    }
}
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: `strings` or `chars` ?

Comment: List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: It seems like the List only represents single characters, why not using chars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static ArrayList<String> myFunction(ArrayList<String> s){

//List we want to return
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

//The first letter will always be capitalized; add it to our result
result.add(s.get(0).toUpperCase());

//Iterate across original list
for (int i = 1; i < s.size(); i++){
    
    //If the current letter is equal to the previous letter
    if (s.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(s.get(i-1))){
        
        //Add the letter to our result as is (lower case)
        result.add(s.get(i));
        
    } else {
        
        //Otherwise, first add a dash to our result 
        result.add("-");
        
        //Then add the letter to our result as upper case
        result.add(s.get(i).toUpperCase());
        
    }
}

//Return final result
return result;

}
```

**Example**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    myList.add("a");
    myList.add("b");
    myList.add("b");
    myList.add("c");
    myList.add("c");
    myList.add("c");
    myList.add("d");
    myList.add("d");
    myList.add("d");
    myList.add("d");
    
    ArrayList<String> result = myFunction(myList);
    
    for (int i = 0 ; i < result.size(); i++){
        System.out.print(result.get(i) + " ");
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
A - B b - C c c - D d d d
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Java 8 groupingBy:**

You can implement the same using Java8 `groupingBy` feature in which you can group the same elements and find the frequency of each element and add it to a list as shown below:

**Code:**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> input = Arrays.asList("a","b","b","c","c","c","d","d","d","d");

        Map<String,Long> countMap = input.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                    LinkedHashMap::new,Collectors.counting()));

        List<String> outputList = new ArrayList<>();
        AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger();
        countMap.forEach((k,v) -> {
            for(int i = 0; i < v; i++){
                if(i==0){
                    outputList.add(k.toUpperCase());
                } else{
                    outputList.add(k);
                }
            }
            if(c.get() < countMap.size()-1){
                outputList.add("-");
            }
            c.getAndIncrement();
        });
        System.out.println(outputList);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[A, -, B, b, -, C, c, c, -, D, d, d, d]
```